# Android AlertDialog not showing on else statement but works on my IF statement

Tags: android, if-statement, location

I have wasted many hours trying to look for the reason why this alertDialog is not showing on my else state but works on the IF statement here is my code.

```
if (locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) && locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){  
    setupMapIfRequired();
}else{  
    Log.d("turn on location Services", "turn on gps " + "a" + ": " + "aa");
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please turn on gps provider location services...................", 1000).show();
    startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
    showDialog();
}
```

can anyone help me_? note . this is only problem area on my code so I only posted this part. the code works if I place the showDialog(); on IF statement but it doesnt work on the else part where I call the location services setting.

here is the showDialog(); function

```
private void showDialog() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            ab.setTitle("Hello!!");
            ab.setMessage("ALL ARE EQUAL");
            ab.setCancelable(false);
            ab.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
            AlertDialog ad = ab.create();

            ad.show();    
    }
```

here is the logcat

```
   08-07 16:15:39.191: I/u(8104): Making Creator dynamically
   08-07 16:15:39.241: I/Google Maps Android API(8104): Google Play services client    version: 5077000
   08-07 16:15:39.241: I/dalvikvm(8104): Could not find method gui.a, referenced from method gqh.a
   08-07 16:15:39.241: W/dalvikvm(8104): VFY: unable to resolve static method 24934:   Lgui;.a (Landroid/content/Context;)Lgrh;
   08-07 16:15:39.241: D/dalvikvm(8104): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0003
   08-07 16:15:39.241: E/dalvikvm(8104): Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
   08-07 16:15:39.241: W/dalvikvm(8104): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4090 (Lgpq;) in Lgpr;
   08-07 16:15:39.241: D/dalvikvm(8104): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
   08-07 16:15:39.241: E/dalvikvm(8104): Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
   08-07 16:15:39.241: W/dalvikvm(8104): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4090 (Lgpq;) in Lgpr;
   08-07 16:15:39.241: D/dalvikvm(8104): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
   08-07 16:15:39.241: E/dalvikvm(8104): Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
   08-07 16:15:39.241: W/dalvikvm(8104): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4090 (Lgpq;) in Lgpr;
   08-07 16:15:39.241: D/dalvikvm(8104): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
   08-07 16:15:39.241: D/dalvikvm(8104): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x5ea1 at 0x0a in Lgpr;.a
   08-07 16:15:39.241: D/dalvikvm(8104): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x5ea1 at 0x0c in Lgpr;.a
   08-07 16:15:39.241: D/dalvikvm(8104): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x5ea1 at 0x0a in Lgpr;.a
   08-07 16:15:39.241: I/Google Maps Android API(8104): Google Play services package version: 5089032
   08-07 16:15:39.241: W/dalvikvm(8104): VFY: unable to resolve static field 20875 (t) in Lyo;
   08-07 16:15:39.241: D/dalvikvm(8104): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000e
   08-07 16:15:39.251: W/dalvikvm(8104): VFY: unable to resolve static field 20875 (t) in Lyo;
   08-07 16:15:39.251: D/dalvikvm(8104): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000d
   08-07 16:15:39.281: I/dalvikvm(8104): Failed resolving Lcom/google/android/gms/location  /internal/ParcelableGeofence; interface 4023 'Lglm;'
   08-07 16:15:39.281: W/dalvikvm(8104): Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence;' failed
   08-07 16:15:39.281: E/dalvikvm(8104): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence', referenced from method gls.a
   08-07 16:15:39.281: W/dalvikvm(8104): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 2086 (Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence;) in Lgls;
    8-07 16:15:39.281: D/dalvikvm(8104): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0019
    08-07 16:15:39.301: D/dalvikvm(8104): GC_CONCURRENT freed 972K, 31% free 7457K/10691K,    paused 0ms+0ms
    08-07 16:15:39.311: D/turn on location Services(8104): turn on gps a: aa
    08-07 16:15:39.371: I/PGA(8104): New SOCKET connection: le.johjiprosign (pid 8104, tid    8104)
```

Comment: So you're starting a new activity and the old activity where the dialog would be showing is not visible.

Comment: even If I try to put the showDialog(); before startActivity i Still don't get the dialog.

Comment: ok , I even tried removing the startAcvity on the else statement and left only the showDialog(); it is still not working .

Comment: Nothing particularly wrong in the code (well, the `1000` param to `Toast` is wrong but it shouldn't cause the problem you're seeing). What happens in your code after this part? Consider debugging your code.

Comment: I found a way to fix the program temporarily by creating a new screen then prompting the user the dialog I created.

Comment: Ok, finally solved the issue the dialogbox won't appear if it doesn't have a context. so thats why in my If statement the context is the map , and on my else is statement it doesn't have any context.